# Problemas en while con if para acumular

Tags: java, loops

Tengo un problema quiero hacer un acumulado de piezas y pagos dentro de un `while` y después acumular en base al empleado y posterior pintar los datos en pantalla.

Pero se salta la información relacionada con el nombre por una columna.

```
2939    DELIA.MORENO    13170   $299.84 //este es el dato correcto si solo busco
```

este empleado.

Si busco todos los empleados es ahi donde sale el detalle.

```
 2912   ASIGNACION1 3941    $106.41

 2913   ASIGNACION2 1358    $38.67

 2914   CAPTURISTA1 2208    $66.31

 2936   JORGE.DIAZ  10544   $327.09

 2938   APOLINARIA.AGUSTIN  20  $0.52

 2939   DELIA.MORENO    17168   $384.93

 2940   DIANA.HERNANDEZ 13170   $299.84

 2941   GUILLERMO.BELLO 16507   $374.72

 2944   ELENA.ZAVALA    16380   $370.13

 2945   ALEJANDRA.ESCALANTE 20198   $453.7

 2946   NORMA.ESTRADA   12941   $298.71

 2947   SANDRA.CORONADO 20272   $456.55

 2947   SANDRA.CORONADO 15232   $342.61
```

Y Delia Moreno tiene otras piezas.

Aquí el código para este cálculo.

```
$_Query = "SELECT CR.CORTE_NUM,count(RL.codigo_qp) cant,RL.USUARIO_ID,US.USER_NAME "
 + " from XXQP.XXQP_REMESA_CORTE_LN_TBL rl left join XXQP.XXQP_REMESA_CORTE_HD_TBL cr on RL.CORTE_ID = CR.CORTE_ID "
 + " inner join APPLSYS.FND_USER US on US.USER_ID=RL.USUARIO_ID "
 + " where 1 = 1";   

if(!StRemesa.equals("")){
    $_Query = $_Query +" and cr.remesa_id="+StRemesa; //Remesa
}
if(!StCapturista.equals("")){
    $_Query = $_Query +" and rl.usuario_id="+StCapturista;//Capturista
}
if(!StFIni.equals("")){ //Fechas
    $_Query = $_Query +" and rl.fecha>=to_date('"+StFIni+" 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') and rl.fecha<=to_date('"+StFFin+" 23:59:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')";
}

$_Query = $_Query +" and rl.origen=3 and rl.usuario_id not in (2731,2912,2913,2914,2936) and rl.estatus!='CANCELADO' group by CR.CORTE_NUM,RL.USUARIO_ID,US.USER_NAME "
 + "order by RL.USUARIO_ID,CR.CORTE_NUM";
rs1 = st1.executeQuery($_Query);

while (rs1.next()) {
    StNCap = rs1.getString("USUARIO_ID");
    StCap = rs1.getString("USER_NAME");

    $_Query = "SELECT HP.PARTY_NAME,LK.MEANING, COALESCE(IT.ATTRIBUTE19,'0.00') comision from XXQP.XXQP_REMESA_CORTE_HD_TBL cr inner join "
        + "XXQP.XXQP_REMESA_TBL r on CR.REMESA_ID = R.REMESA_ID inner join APPLSYS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES lk "
        + "on CR.PLAZA_ID = LK.LOOKUP_CODE and LK.LOOKUP_TYPE='XXQP_PLAZAS' and LK.LANGUAGE='ESA' inner join AR.HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS hz "
        + "on  r.cliente_id = HZ.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID inner join AR.HZ_PARTIES hp on  HZ.PARTY_ID = HP.PARTY_ID inner join INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B "
        + "it on r.producto_id = IT.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID and r.almacen_id = IT.ORGANIZATION_ID where  CR.CORTE_NUM='"+rs1.getString("corte_num")+"'";
    rs2 = Gdr.consultar($_Query, 2);

    if (rs2.next()){
        StComm = rs2.getString("comision");
        Pago=Double.parseDouble(rs2.getString("comision")) * Integer.parseInt(rs1.getString("cant"));

        out.print("<tr bgcolor='lightgray' ALIGN='CENTER'>");
        if (cont >= 1) {
            if (!empleado.equals(rs1.getString("USUARIO_ID"))) {
                out.print(tr bgcolor='lightgray' ALIGN='CENTER');
                out.print(td + StNCap);
                out.print(/td);
                out.print(td + StCap);
                out.print(/td);
                out.print(td + piezas);
                out.print(/td);
                out.print(td + format.format(PagoTotal));
                out.print(/td);
                out.print(/tr);
                piezas = 0;
                PagoTotal = 0.0;
            }
        }
        empleado = rs1.getString("USUARIO_ID");
        PagoTotal +=Pago;
        piezas += rs1.getInt("cant");
        cont = cont+1;
    }
    rs2.close();
    if (r == 0) {
%>
<tr bgcolor='white' ALIGN='CENTER'>
<%
        r = 1;
    } else {
        r = 0;
%>
<tr bgcolor='#E6E6E6' ALIGN='CENTER'>
<% } %>
</tr>
<%    
}
out.print(tr bgcolor='lightgray' ALIGN='CENTER');
out.print(td + StNCap);
out.print(/td);
out.print(td + StCap );
out.print(/td);
out.print(td + piezas );
out.print(/td);
out.print(td> + format.format(PagoTotal));
out.print(/td);
out.print(/tr);
st1.close();
Gdr.cerrar();
```

Comment: No veo tu while por ninguna parte!

Comment: fue reemplazado por el if (rs2.next()) {

Comment: Jairo, puedes poner el codigo de rs2, es el resultado de alguna consulta a  una base de datos, un cursor????

Comment: @sioesi Recien edite el codigo . Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en el   `if (rs2.next())` que tienes dentro del `while` ya que estás llamando al método `next()` sin saber si habrá otro registro o no.

Asumiendo que estás usando un `Iterator`, una forma de comprobarlo es usando el método `.hasNext()`, dejando el código tal que así:

```
while (rs1.hasNext()) {
    rs1.next();
    //Parte del código que tu tenias
    if(rs2.hasNext()){
       rs2.next();
       //resto del código
    }
}
```

También puedes valorar cambiar el tipo de bucle por un `for`, con el que seguramente puedas tener más control

Comment: No veo el problema que mencionas. Nota que hay 2 variables distintas, `rs1`, `rs2`, para 2 consultas distintas.

Comment: cierto, se me pasó completamente, revisaré el código para dar una respuesta mas adecuada, aun así el problema de que se salte registros va por el mismo sitio.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no muestra los datos del último empleado, prueba algo asi:

```
if (rs2.next()) {
    StComm = rs2.getString("comision");
    Pago = Double.parseDouble(rs2.getString("comision")) * Integer.parseInt(rs1.getString("cant"));

    if (cont >= 1) {
        if (!empleado.equals(rs1.getString("USUARIO_ID"))) {
            out.print("<tr bgcolor='lightgray' ALIGN='CENTER'>");
            out.print("<td>" + StNCap);
            out.print("</td>");
            out.print("<td>" + StCap);
            out.print("</td>");
            out.print("<td>" + piezas);
            out.print("</td>");
            out.print("<td>" + format.format(PagoTotal));
            out.print("</td>");
            out.print("</tr>");
            piezas = 0;
            PagoTotal = 0.0;
        }
    }

    empleado = rs1.getString("USUARIO_ID");
    PagoTotal += Pago;
    piezas += rs1.getInt("cant");
    cont = cont + 1;

}

if (cont >= 1) {
    out.print("<tr bgcolor='lightgray' ALIGN='CENTER'>");
    out.print("<td>" + StNCap);
    out.print("</td>");
    out.print("<td>" + StCap);
    out.print("</td>");
    out.print("<td>" + piezas);
    out.print("</td>");
    out.print("<td>" + format.format(PagoTotal));
    out.print("</td>");
    out.print("</tr>");
}
```

Suerte!

Comment: El ultimo empleado si lo imprime , este proceso lo hago fuera del ciclo, he actualizado el codigo en donde se muetra esa parte, ahora bien el problema es que el primer empleado no lo imprime. Las cantidades si estan bien, pero los empleados no tienes correspondencia con las cantidades